# How to write instructions to write log records of Selenium automation test results in batch file

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, batch-file, nunit

My batch file to run Selenium Automation test cases that were written using C# NUnit is as follows:

```
set test_runner="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe"
set test_dlls="C:\Users\user1\source\repos\TestProject1\TestProject1\bin\Debug\net6.0\TestProject1.dll"
set tests="Test1_Login,Test2_Register,Test3_Logout"
set nunit-console nunit.tests.dll /out:TestResult.txt
%test_runner% %test_dlls% /tests:%tests%
```

How can I add instructions to the batch file to generate a log file of the automation test case result?

Answer (score 1):

adding `logger:trx` at the end of last line would create result log in the same directory as Bat file

```
%test_runner% %test_dlls% /tests:%tests% /logger:trx
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use .runsettings file you can add NUnit configuration section like

```
<RunSettings>
    <NUnit>
            <TestOutputXml>PathWhereTestResultsFileHasToWrite</TestOutputXml>
    </NUnit>
</RunSettings>
```

and this will generate your test result file.